# Get encoded String using Fernet

Tags: java, fernet

So I decided to encode a String using Fernet

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
private static final Key key = new Key("myrandomkey");

public static Token encrypt(String message){
    return Token.generate(key, message);
}
```

How would I go about obtaining the encoded String? Since the token provides timestamp and iv, but not the encoded String

I tried getting the cipherText of the token, but that just gives me a weird String (Ex: "[B@6f7122f9"), when the encrypted String should be something like: 78APXA4zMBNX1REjh21AXzAx1YXor4ozq8RxABCZ4uo=
Also, cipherText is private/protected

PS: I want to send the encodedstring over requests (Spring Framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of testing, the solution was to .serialise()

That method will return the encoded String

So:

```
public static String encrypt(String message){
    return Token.generate(key, message).serialise();
}
```